# Blackberry Push notification : Java.io.IOException:Network operation(Subscribe)failed. Make sure that Content Provider Url is accessible

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

I am working on blackberry Push Notification and facing a big issue while registering from the device.  I'm getting the Exception:

> Java.io.IOException:Network operation(Subscribe)failed. Make sure that Content Provider Url is accessible..

I go through this [guide](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/30161/Push_Service_SDK-Getting_Started_Guide--) and set up all things according to it.

However I am unable to register.  My tomcat server is running and I can access content provider URL from my computer and the same from device's browser.

```
PC URL is: https:/loaclhost:8443/sample-push-initiator
```

I changed local host to IP address of my Computer. and can access it over WiFi.

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: for registering your device for push notification, you have to activate the BIS on your device.

Comment: Also the PC URL is incorrect should be https://localhost:8443/sample-push-initiator just correcting to the two typos

Comment: I have a BIS plan on my device.

Comment: if you using wifi, then turn off it and use the BIS and try again.

Comment: i have already done it...i turned off my wifi and checked it with sim having BIS plan...it is accessible from browser but on the time of registration throwing exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your push initiator URL must be publicly accessible from the internet to be accessible from your device. Using localhost or any local IP address (e.g. 192.168.0.2) won't work.

You'll have to set up your router to forward traffic on port 8443 to your PC's local IP.

You should ensure that this URL is accessible from your blackberry normal web browser (not the hotspot browser) before trying with the sample push app.